My Android Studio java project builds but doesn't run on virtual devise
I'm developing a mobile Java app in Android Studio. It's supposed to work on Pixel 2 API 29 (Android 10). The project used to work fine but now it just stopped running on a devise. The emulator itself turns on.
Here is the build output:
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project D:\Lazy Lorry

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 6 s 215 ms
> Task :app:createDebugVariantModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 36s
31 actionable tasks: 31 up-to-date

Build Analyzer results available

And here is timeline in notifications:
Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
Gradle build finished in 41 s 666 ms
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project D:\Lazy Lorry
* daemon started successfully
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

How can I fix the issue?

That an app compiles just means the basic Java systax is fulfilled. Posting the compile log and upload log will not help. Instead you should post the logcat log of your app especially the stacktrace and error message when it crashes. Just remove the existing logs and replace them with the stack trace.

@Robert there was one error "Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online". I read an advise to wipe data of virtual devise. I did that. And then i got another error such as avg is running if it's not delete file .lock

I've tried various ways to solve the issue but the only effective one was to delete the current virtual device and install an identical one to replace it. Hope it helps!
